# Count is slowing down query too much. How can I refactor this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been working on this for a while..

I've got the inner query running much faster, but the count seems to be slowing this down..

I only need to return the payments where the "type_id" occurs > 13 times, but this count seems to be greatly slowing this down... been running for over an hour..

How could I refactor this to increase the speed?  It's running over a lot of data..

I was trying to Keep it DRY to avoid multiple subqueries of the same table.. But, ultimately, I need this to be much faster..

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(
                p.type_id
            ) OVER(PARTITION BY
                p.type_id
            ) cnt,
            p.pay_key puk, a.pay_key auk, a.pay_code
FROM payment p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pay_key
                                ORDER BY allotment_uid
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM allotment a
      WHERE pay_code = 101 AND deleted = 'N'
     ) a
     ON a.pay_key = p.pay_key AND
        seqnum = 1

                    INNER JOIN submission submission ON
                submission.event_num = a.event_num
            AND
                submission.client_id = a.client_id
            AND
                submission.submitter_num = a.submitter_num
            AND
                submission.unit = a.unit
            AND
                submission.submission_num = a.submission_num
            INNER JOIN submitter submitter ON
                submitter.event_num = submission.event_num
            AND
                submitter.submitter_num = submission.submitter_num
            AND
                submitter.client_id = submission.client_id
        WHERE
                p.type_id <> 0
            AND
                p.type_id IS NOT NULL
            AND
                p.deleted = 'N'
            AND
                p.date_paid >= TO_DATE('2017-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
            AND
                p.date_paid < TO_DATE('2017-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + 1) a

                where a.cnt > 13;
```

---

explain plan:

```
Plan hash value: 3862283857

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                         | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                  |                               | 14159 |   967K|       |   501K (15)| 00:00:20 |       |       |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                             |                               | 14159 |   967K|       |   501K (15)| 00:00:20 |       |       |
|   2 |   WINDOW SORT                                     |                               | 14159 |  2737K|  2920K|   501K (15)| 00:00:20 |       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                                   |                               | 14159 |  2737K|       |   501K (15)| 00:00:20 |       |       |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                                  |                               | 14159 |  2475K|       |   487K (15)| 00:00:20 |       |       |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                                 |                               | 14159 |  2101K|       |   473K (15)| 00:00:19 |       |       |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | PAYMENT                       | 70753 |  2072K|       | 48472   (1)| 00:00:02 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                           | LK_PAYMENT_DATEPRNT_PROTAX_01 | 52192 |       |       |   366   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  8 |       VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                       |                               |     1 |   122 |       |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   9 |        WINDOW SORT                                |                               |     1 |    53 |       |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 10 |         TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| ALLOTMENT                     |     1 |    53 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|* 11 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                         | LK_ALLOTMENT_04               |     2 |       |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  12 |      PARTITION HASH ITERATOR                      |                               |     1 |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 13 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID           | SUBMISSION                    |     1 |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 14 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                          | LK_SUBMISSION_01              |     1 |       |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 15 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                              | VSS_SUBMITTER_001             |     1 |    19 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("A"."CNT">13)
   6 - filter("P"."DELETED"='N')
   7 - access("P"."DATE_PAID">=TO_DATE(' 2017-07-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "P"."DATE_PAID"<TO_DATE(' 2017-07-06 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
       filter("P"."TYPE_ID"<>0 AND "P"."TYPE_ID" IS NOT NULL)
   8 - filter("SEQNUM"=1)
  10 - filter("PAY_CODE"=101 AND "DELETED"='N')
  11 - access("A"."UNIQUE_KEY"="P"."UNIQUE_KEY")
  13 - filter("SUBMISSION"."CLIENT_ID"="A"."CLIENT_ID")
  14 - access("SUBMISSION"."EVENT_NUM"="A"."EVENT_NUM" AND "SUBMISSION"."SUBMITTER_NUM"="A"."SUBMITTER_NUM" AND "SUBMISSION"."SUBMISSION_NUM"="A"."SUBMISSION_NUM" AND 
              "SUBMISSION"."UNIT"="A"."UNIT")
  15 - access("SUBMITTER"."EVENT_NUM"="SUBMISSION"."EVENT_NUM" AND "SUBMITTER"."SUBMITTER_NUM"="SUBMISSION"."SUBMITTER_NUM" AND "SUBMITTER"."CLIENT_ID"="SUBMISSION"."CLIENT_ID")
```

Comment: I think it's a number of columns load rather than data, can you try is by selecting few of specific columns ?

Comment: Yes, it works if I narrow down the date range, but the count  seems to be greatly slowing  it..

Comment: Does an explain plan show any operations with high costs, like full table scans?

Comment: Maybe you can make type_id as an index so it speeds up the query search.

Comment: I don't have access to change the index, but I believe that's already included.

I've added an explain plan above.

Answer (score 0):

try counting the filtered rows before joins e.g.

```
SELECT
      p.cnt, p.puk, a.pay_key auk, a.pay_code
FROM (
      SELECT
            COUNT(p.type_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.type_id) cnt
          , p.pay_key                                      puk
      FROM payment
      WHERE p.type_id <> 0
      AND p.type_id IS NOT NULL
      AND p.deleted = 'N'
      AND p.date_paid >= TO_DATE('2017-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      AND p.date_paid < TO_DATE('2017-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + 1
     ) P
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  a.*
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pay_key
                  ORDER BY allotment_uid
                  ) AS seqnum
            FROM allotment a
            WHERE pay_code = 101
            AND deleted = 'N'
      ) a ON a.pay_key = p.pay_key
            AND seqnum = 1
      INNER JOIN submission submission ON submission.event_num = a.event_num
            AND submission.client_id = a.client_id
            AND submission.submitter_num = a.submitter_num
            AND submission.unit = a.unit
            AND submission.submission_num = a.submission_num
      INNER JOIN submitter submitter ON submitter.event_num = submission.event_num
            AND submitter.submitter_num = submission.submitter_num
            AND submitter.client_id = submission.client_id
) d
WHERE d.cnt > 13;
```

Comment: Not sure that will work, as I only need to count those that have a certain "type_id" which occurs more than 13 times.

Comment: Have you tried it? The same where condition is used so  I  don't see how it differs with respect to type_id.

Comment: Well, I need payments with a type id and pay_code that occur > 13 times in a time span. the pay_code is attached to the allotment.  It seems that would be omitted from the count with this..